# How to load bitmap to Glance composable via Coil Uri?

Tags: android, coil, glance-appwidget

I am following the sample code from [ImageGlanceWidget](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/main/AppWidget/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/appwidget/glance/image/ImageGlanceWidget.kt) to load a bitmap to Glance via Uri.

As mentioned in the comments from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361579/15597975) I have replaced `getImageProvider()` method with below code. However, when I do this I get error:
`Error in Glance App Widget java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:/data/user/0/com.example.myappname/cache/image_cache/56448.....8e0ad2fac0.1`.

How can I pull the bitmap from the coil disk cache?

```kotlin
private fun getImageProvider(context: Context, coilPath: String): ImageProvider {
    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, coilPath.toUri())
    return ImageProvider(bitmap)
}
```

#### Parameter Values

```kotlin
val coilPath = context.imageLoader.diskCache?.get("https://picsum.photos/${width.roundToInt()}/${height.roundToInt()}")?.data?.toFile()?.path!! /*uses worker context*/
val context = LocalContext.current /*pass in context from glance composable to getImageProvider*/
```

#### Full Stack Trace

```
E/GlanceAppWidget: Error in Glance App Widget
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /data/user/0/com.example.mpappname/cache/image_cache/56448c7214ea904b18f01d34bdd997afd53c1c976abda4a67546d08e0ad2fac0.1
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2013)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1842)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1518)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:2322)
        at com.example.stockwidgetv1.clean.widget.glance.utility.WidgetDummy.getImageProvider2(WidgetDummy.kt:145)
        at com.example.stockwidgetv1.clean.widget.glance.utility.WidgetDummy.access$getImageProvider2(WidgetDummy.kt:44)
        at com.example.stockwidgetv1.clean.widget.glance.utility.WidgetDummy$Content$1.invoke(WidgetDummy.kt:101)
        at com.example.stockwidgetv1.clean.widget.glance.utility.WidgetDummy$Content$1.invoke(WidgetDummy.kt:97)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.glance.layout.BoxKt.Box(Box.kt:74)
        at com.example.stockwidgetv1.clean.widget.glance.utility.WidgetDummy.Content(WidgetDummy.kt:92)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$setContent$1$1.invoke(GlanceAppWidget.kt:404)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$setContent$1$1.invoke(GlanceAppWidget.kt:404)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$setContent$1.invoke(GlanceAppWidget.kt:398)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$setContent$1.invoke(GlanceAppWidget.kt:397)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3173)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:950)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget.setContent-Cox8Y-g(GlanceAppWidget.kt:397)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget.access$setContent-Cox8Y-g(GlanceAppWidget.kt:72)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$composeForSize$2.invokeSuspend(GlanceAppWidget.kt:372)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$composeForSize$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$composeForSize$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:169)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget.composeForSize-AAqiGWc$glance_appwidget_release(GlanceAppWidget.kt:365)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget$Api31Impl$composeAllSizes$2$allViews$1$1.invokeSuspend(GlanceAppWidget.kt:431)
E/GlanceAppWidget:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory?hl=en#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) to get a `Bitmap` from a `File` pointing to a bitmap image.

It would be cleaner to [just ask Coil to load the image](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil#requests). That way, you won't be trying to mess with Coil's cache (which Coil might also be manipulating, such as clearing entries), and you can deal with the race condition of your image have been ejected from the cache before you try using it:

```kotlin
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
    .build()
val bitmap = imageLoader.execute(request).drawable.bitmap
```

Comment: thanks, in my use case I won't be making http requests for image. how would I get this to work with local file i.e. `.data(file)`? P.s. the second hyper link in your answer is same as the first...

Comment: @mairs8: "in my use case I won't be making http requests for image" -- according to your question, you are loading an image from `picsum.photos`. Regardless, try passing a `File` object to `data()`. A `File` at least [works with `load()`](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil#imageviews). And sorry about the URL -- I forgot that GitHub doesn't copy the URL to the clipboard when you click the link icon the way that the Android docs do. It's fixed now.

Comment: "Use BitmapFactory.decodeFile() to get a Bitmap from a File pointing to a bitmap image.". I can successfully see my bitmap saved in the file location in device file explorer. However when I use decodefile(file) I get error `E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/data/user/0/com.example.myappname/files/glance/64/130_101.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. Any ideas?

Comment: the exact `file` path value is the following `file:///data/user/0/com.example.myappname/files/glance/64/130_101.png`

Comment: @mairs8: You appear to be creating your `File` object incorrectly. The filesystem path should not have a `file:` prefix on it.

Comment: thanks, I was using `uri.toString` instead of `uri.path` which was adding the `file:\\` prefix