# Display list of scrollable images inside Android Widget using Jetpack Glance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget

I am looking for suggestions on how to display list of scrollable images(using image URLs) inside android widget using jetpack glance.
I am currently using LazyColumn to display list items inside the widget.
Currently the alpha version [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance#version_100_2) contains Image composables that accepts Image Bitmaps as input.

Can this be acheived without using glance(since it is still in alpha phase of development)? If yes, could you please share what would the best approach.

Reference : [Similar_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361073/how-to-load-images-from-the-internet-into-a-widget-with-jetpack-glance). Also any updates on the next release of glance? or Information related to stable release?

Thank You

PS: New to android development.

................................................